# C# Crystal Reports Printing Page Size Incorrect

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I'm developing a c# program to print Crystal Reports document. The program takes rpt raw file and send it to printer.

```
ReportDocument crrpt = new ReportDocument();
crrpt.Load(pathtorptfile);

crrpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = settings.Print_printer;
crrpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

The above code can print. The problem is the page size does not seem correct. It is different from the page size in the rpt file (when opened in Crystal Reports).

When opened in Crystal Reports, the size is half A4 (which is what I need). And printing it within Crystal, also gives the half the page. However, when I print with above code, it prints in top half page and leave the bottom half page empty. (Sample https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pSjp.jpg).

Printing within Crystal Reports (on the left - one I need) vs Printing with above code (on the right).

Appreciate any helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your default printer paper size to A5 and orientation to landscape. Which you are using in printing code. And then try again.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I get half page which is good, but the report is cropped on the right due to oversize report I created. And I wish to keep the same report size. Any other solution?

Comment: Create custom paper size for your printer, just more than the what currently is in A5 size. And select that custom paper size for your printer.  http://m.windowsitpro.com/windows-7/q-how-do-i-create-custom-paper-size-printing-windows-7